# AIR / Flex - AlivePDF print whole canvas

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, air, alivepdf

Is there a possibility to print a whole canvas UI element (and all its children) using [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/)?

I know that the [normal way](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/) would be to add each element separately, but if there is whole bunch of elements (text, image..) that is a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to create an image from the Canvas control and to add the image to the PDF. That might be lower res than you would like, and the text would not be selectable.

```
    var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

    myBitmapData.draw(canvas);

    myPDF.addImage(new Bitmap(myBitmapData, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true),
                    0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 
                    ImageFormat.JPG, 100, 1);
```